# two question about phpMailer security when hosting my app?

Tags: php, security, localhost, phpmailer, web-deployment

Currently I am using **phpMailer** for sending emails to my Gmail account in a form submition. the code that I used for sending email is similar to the below code:

```
###################
/* sendeng email */
###################
use phpMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
if ($sehat === true) {
    require_once "../phpMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "../phpMailer/SMTP.php";
    require_once "../phpMailer/Exception.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    //smtp settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "myGmail@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = 'myPassword';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

    //email settings
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($commEmail, $commName);
    $mail->addAddress("myGmail@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = ("$commEmail ($commTopic)");
    $mail->Body = "<div style='text-align:right; direction:rtl;'>" . nl2br(strip_tags($commMess)) . "</div>";
    // $mail->Body = nl2br(strip_tags($commMess));
    // $mail->AltBody = nl2br(strip_tags($commMess));
    // $mail->Body = $commMess;
    /* for other language messages */
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    if($mail->send()){
        $status = "success";
        $response = "Email is sent!";
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "failed";
        $response = "Something is wrong: <br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
}
```

I don't have any problem with sending email. But my **first** question is where I am using `$mail->Password = 'myPassword';` in my code. Actually I am writing and debugging the code on a localhost (WAMPSERVER), and I used my real password instead of **myPassword** in the code. But after finishing the app I am going to host it to a real server (deploy my app). My question is that with this code, could **host provider** access to my Gmail password? And if so what is the solution to that? Is it a bug in **phpMailer** or I am wrong?

The **second** question is that when I want to send form data to my Gmail account, I must change the setting of my Gmail to **"lower security"** in this **localhost** version. If I deploy my app and it becomes available online, again I must do that (lower security of Gmail) or there are better ways? Because now when I return Gmail security setting to **normal** state the phpMailer does not send data.

Comment: Anything the server can do, anyone with control over the server can do too. If your server can, by necessity, send email via Gmail and it needs the password to do so, then the host provider who administers the server can by necessity do the same if they wanted to.

Comment: How should your webserver send out the mail using Gmail if it would not have your credentials?

Comment: @Nico Haase thanks for your comment, I am not very familiar with hosting issues, so I thought that maybe I could do something for that problem, but what about lowering the Gmail security setting?  is it necessary in online version?

Comment: You should also use their API to send emails instead of setting the account to "lower security". That flag usually gets reverted once in a while (they're pushing people to use their API instead of sending through SMTP). And using their API, you get specific credentials for that app, which you easily can remove without modifying your account credentials (which should never be shared with anyone or be put on any server)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is that with this code, could host provider access to my Gmail password?

Yes.

> And if so what is the solution to that?

Don't use a host you don't trust.

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to be able to trust your host, but there is one step that can help avoid all that this implies: using XOAUTH2 for authentication.

With this mechanism you do not have to store a real ID and password on your server; you need to use them in a one-off operation to obtain a token that can be limited to gmail operations. There are [code examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps) for this, along with [a utility script you can use to obtain your auth token](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/get_oauth_token.php), and [a wiki article to help you configure it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) (though it could use updating; contributions welcome). However, be aware that using OAuth is generally a complicated and unpleasant experience that contains many potential ways to mess things up. In this use case, it does provide a security enhancement as it means you don't have to leave your real google credentials lying around.

A scrupulous hosting provider will allow you to encrypt your VM's disk images in a way that means they can't read your data from the hypervisor, and if they don't also have SSH access to your instance, your data should be fairly well protected from them.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I need to learn a lot before deploying my app!!! and about your last tip (case sensitive) I think that the first **"phpMailer"** is the  name of folder that the library codes is there. am I wrong? and if no I called that folder with lower case "p" not "P".

Comment: Nope, you're mixing up namespaces and folder names; `use` statements are not folder names, they are local aliases of namespaced classes and functions. If you're new to PHP, about the first thing you should do is learn to use composer. It's not that complicated, and once you figure it out, you won't want to do without it.

Comment: so why the code is running and does not give me any error?

Comment: That's a good question – so I checked and it turns out [I was completely wrong](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)! Namespaces are *not* case sensitive, which is why you're not getting an error; it's never occurred to me that they were not, as variables and properties are! I'll delete that note from my answer to save myself future embarrassment... Regardless, they still have little to do with your folder names.